# Clicking on <li> list item not using Selenium Java

Tags: java, list, selenium

The following list represents page navigation buttons:

```
<div class="list">
 <ul class="pageNav">
  <li class="paginate_button ">
   <a href="#" controls="Tables_Table_0" data-idx="0" tabindex="0">1</a></li>
  <li class="paginate_button ">
   <a href="#" controls="Tables_Table_0" data-idx="1" tabindex="0">2</a></li>
  <li class="paginate_button ">
   <a href="#" controls="Tables_Table_0" data-idx="2" tabindex="0">3</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

To go to the second page for instance, I am using this Selenium Java code:

```
//after setting up webdriver
List<WebElement> li = driver.findElements(By.className("pageNav"));
System.out.println(li.get(2).getText());
li.get(2).click();
```

It's printing the text correctly "2", but not clicking or navigating correctly as if I was manually doing it on the actual website. I also tried replacing the link with an actual link like:
`<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our page</a>`

But still no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You're clicking on the "<li>" element, but you should click on it's "<a>" child element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of these below code.

In your tried code, I have noticed that you were using `class` locator to click on `links` element. But your `<ul>` tag does not contains the link. Inside `<ul>` tag, `<li>` tag is present and each `<li>` tag contains separate `<a>` tag.

so, here you should go with `xpath` or `cssSelector` locator.

**Method 1) By using xpath locator**

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pageNav']/li/a"));
System.out.println(links.size());

links.get(1).click(); //indexing start from 0, if you want to click on second link then pass indexing as 1.
```

**Suggestion:-** Instead of using `absolute xpath`, use `relative xpath`.

**Method 2) By using cssSelector locator**

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ul.pageNav>li>a"));
System.out.println(links.size());

links.get(1).click(); //indexing start from 0, if you want to click on second link then pass indexing as 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
    //getting all the anchor tag elements and storing in a list

    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pageNav']//li[starts-with(@class,'paginate_button')]/a"));
    System.out.println(links.size());

    //performs click on second links
    links.get(1).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're facing any abnormal difficulty which you are not able to handle directly , then you can first try to move to that element using actions class then click it as below:

```
 WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.list > ul.pageNav li:nth-child(2));
 Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 action.moveToElement(we).click().build().perform();
```